# Thread-safe way to increment and return an integer in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, increment

In a single-threaded application I use code like this:

```
Interface
    function GetNextUID : integer;
Implementation
    function GetNextUID : integer;
    const
      cUID : integer = 0;
    begin
      inc( cUID );
      result := cUID;
    end;
```

This could of course be implemented as a singleton object, etc. - I'm just giving the simplest possible example.

Q: How can I modify this function (or design a class) to achieve the same result safely from concurrent threads?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, everyone. I had somehow managed to convince myself that interlockedincrement was incrementing the value in place without returning it - not that it would make any sense that way, but I got stuck on that all the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `Interlocked*` functions:

```
    function GetNextUID : integer;
    {$J+} // Writeble constants
    const
      cUID : integer = 0;
    begin
      Result := InterlockedIncrement(cUID);
    end;
```

More modern Delphi versions have renamed these methods into `Atomic*` (like `AtomicDecrement`, `AtomicIncrement`, etc), so the example code becomes this:

```
    function GetNextUID : integer;
    {$J+} // Writeble constants
    const
      cUID : integer = 0;
    begin
      Result := AtomicIncrement(cUID);
    end;
```

Comment: and +1 for explicitly stating {$J+}. Although I would prefer to make GetNextUID a class function and use a class var for FUID, just because I dislike abusing constants.

Comment: note: interlocked functions not available in FireMonkey (there should be a cross platform way to increment/decrement?)

Comment: @AnotherProg they replaced the prefix (see edit), now you can change `AtomicIncrement` and similar.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way would probably be to just call [`InterlockedIncrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614(VS.85).aspx) to do the job.

Comment: but note: not available in FireMonkey. Cross Platform way to increment/decrement?

Answer (score 5):

With modern Delphi compilers it is better to use [Increment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked.Increment) function of class [TInterlocked](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked) from unit System.SyncObjs. Something like this:

```
  type
    TMyClass = class
    class var
      FIdCounter: int64;
    var
      FId: int64;
    constructor Create;
    end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  FId := TInterlocked.Increment(FIdCounter);
end;
```

This helps to keep the code platform-independent.